# JLabel mouse events

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

How I can enable the drag and drop event on jlabel ?
I have put an image inside jlabel ,and I want to drag that image to jpanel and open it there .Please can any one help me to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/) lesson of the Java Tutorial.

Comment: this would be applicable for JLabel?

Comment: thnx , but how i can show the user the image moving while he is drag the mouse after pressed it on the JLabel?

Comment: That word is 'thanks'.  You can better express that thanks by taking the effort to spell words properly, rather than using text-speak.  As to your (2nd) question, you might look into TransferHandler.setDragImage(Image) (http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html#setDragImage%28java.awt.Image%29).  If you experience any further problems, I suggest you start a new question & include an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html) of your current code.